# PHP Screenshot - button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a button which saves screenshots, but unfortunately when you click nothing happens

**JavaScript**

```
function take_screenshot() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL()
            $.post("save_screenshot.php", {data: img}, function (file) {
                window.location.href =  "save_screenshot.php?file="+ file
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if($_GET['file']) {
    $file=$_GET['file'];
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        unlink($file);
        exit;
    }
}

if($_POST['data']) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $file = md5(uniqid()) . '.png';
    $uri =  substr($data,strpos($data,",")+1);
    file_put_contents('./'.$file, base64_decode($uri));
    echo $file;
    exit();
}
```

I want to be a screen save as png and me to chose locations. I used the guide on the internet and it seems to me that it should work

Comment: button where it wants to be a, but I did the same only without the great code and also did not work

Comment: i took it http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/take-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-html5-and-javascript.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the `dataUrl`, because it is delimited by `,`

```
function take_screenshot() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL()
            $.post("save_screenshot.php", {data: img.split(',').pop()}, function (file) {
                window.location.href =  "save_screenshot.php?file="+ file
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: some do not understand :(

Comment: unfortunately, it did not work for me on. nothing happens